# Android: show/hide status bar/power bar

Tags: android, show-hide, statusbar

I am trying to create a button where I can hide or show the status bar on my tablet.

I've put in the onCreate

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

and in the buttons
show:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
attrs.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
```

hide:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
```

Any hints/tipps?

//edit

I've looked at this hint here: http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=306
and changed my code like this:

```
private void hideStatusBar() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui"});
    proc.waitFor();
}

private void showStatusBar() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"am","startservice","-n","com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService"});
    proc.waitFor();
}
```

So if I click on my buttons an the methods are called I can see that something is happening because the app is waiting some seconds.
I also looked into LockCat and see that something is happening.

show: http://pastebin.com/CidTRSTi
hide: http://pastebin.com/iPS6Kgbp

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Do you have the fullscreen theme set in the manifest?

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

I don't think you'll be able to go fullscreen without this.

I would use the following to add and remove the fullscreen flag:

```
// Hide status bar
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
// Show status bar
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: No, I haven't added it to the manifest. But when I try, I get the error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/
 Theme.Dark.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen')."

Comment: @B770: There is none named `Theme.Dark.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. There is one named `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`. However, you cannot get rid of the system bar on Android 3.0+ devices that lack off-screen HOME and BACK buttons.

Comment: @CommonWare: I found this: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1265397
here it's possible to hide and show the status bar. I've installed the "Overcome" ROM where this funktion is included and it works. So I tought it would be also possible to put this funktion on an other button...

Comment: ok. I've got it. I forgot to grant su rights to the app. Now everything just works fine :)

Comment: Is it possible to show/hide status bar when scrolling up or down?

Comment: @Rob this is working fine one issue i'm facing is when i do add and clear it shows white statusbar for few milliseconds. which is looking very ood. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 38):

For Some People,  Showing status bar by clearing FLAG_FULLSCREEN may not work,

Here is the solution that worked for me,  ([Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)) ([Flag Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE))

**Hide Status Bar**

```
// Hide Status Bar
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
else {
   View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
  // Hide Status Bar.
   int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

**Show Status Bar**

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
              getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    else {
       View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
      // Show Status Bar.
       int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE;
       decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

Comment: I have same exact code, but status bar is still showing

Answer (score 5):

used for kolin in android
for hide status bar in kolin no need to used semicolon(;) at the  end of the line

```
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

in android using java language for hid status bar

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: It only hides StatusBar, doesn't show.

Answer (score 4):

I know its a very old question, but just in case anyone lands here looking for the newest supported way to hide status bar on the go programmatically, you can do it as follows:

```
window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
```

and to show it again:

```
window.insetsController?.show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
```

Comment: I think should add info about using this way for minSdk < 30:

ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

Answer (score 2):

I've tried so many things.

**Finally, It is the most suitable code to hide and show full screen mode.**

```
private fun hideSystemUi() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(true)
    } else {
        // hide status bar
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    }

}

private fun showSystemUi() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
    } else {
        // Show status bar
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    }

}
```

It Implemented it in this app : **[Android Breakdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mayadi.androidbreakdown)**.

Go to **Videos(Bottom Bar) > Play Any Video > Toggle Fullscreen**

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //hide status bar
    requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE );
    getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin users

**TO SHOW**

`activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

**TO HIDE**

`activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

Answer (score 1):

with this method, using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY the full screen come back with one tap without any implementation. Just copy past this method below and call it where you want in your activity.
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html#EnableFullscreen)

```
private void hideSystemUI() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference - https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

```
// This snippet shows the system bars. It does this by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    mDecorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Activity.setStatusBarVisibility(isVisible: Boolean) {
    //see details https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive
    if (isVisible) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    } else {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to XML fitsSystemWindows parameter:

<RelativeLayout
...
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide only the Status bar, use this

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

window?.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```