# Android, Call API 14 method but should stay compatible with API 4

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, statusbar

If the device is running ICS I want to hide the status bar with:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

But the **View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE** parameter is defined in Android API 14.

My manifest is now:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

and

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

But then it crashes with:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setSystemUiVisibility
```

What can I do to call this method and keep it compatible with Android devices with a lower api level?

Comment: Please check the following links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273186/android-show-hide-status-bar-power-bar
and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Comment: check the api level and call the method only if api >= 14 and on the lower api request full screen. supporting api 4 isn't really necessary imho

Comment: Thanks WarrenFaith, didn't thought of that. [Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >  11] works great!

Comment: Note that it "works great" for Android 2.0 and higher. On Android 1.x, you need to do a bit more to avoid a `VerifyError`.

Comment: Lol, yeah. But minSdkVersion is at 4 ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the version by using

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

and u can check the version before set the parameter

```
if(SDK_INT >= 11 && SDK_INT < 14) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
    }else if(SDK_INT >= 14){
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
    }
```

Comment: View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN is API 11. You will still get a crash on API 10 and lower

Comment: It is of best practice to do

import static android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

rather then

int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

Comment: How would this avoid `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setSystemUiVisibility`? You are still loading code with this method, on an API level that doesn't have this method. Likewise the field `STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN`.

Comment: You can also use the [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) instead of the hard coded SDK integers if you prefer.