# How can I put slider instead of status bar in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

I want to put slider instead of status bar

[image: Screenshot]

How can I do that?

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://s[enter image description here][1]chemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/home_fragment">



        <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
            android:id="@+id/image_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            app:auto_cycle="true"
            app:delay="0"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:destination="@id/home_fragment"
            app:period="1500" />
    
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_slider"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is handled by the theme in the manifest.xml. Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273186/android-show-hide-status-bar-power-bar

Comment: You must first hide statusBar and then you can easily make a slider with a custom height in top of activity.

Comment: okay guys thanks I have done finally but that's not working in drop notch phone