# Hide and show only status bar keeping the content is full screen mode in Android 12 [without depreciate code]

Tags: android, android-12, android-fullscreen

I want to achieve behaviour similar to video attached below from the WEBTOONS app, where content is in full screen and they hide and show status bar

[Video of required behaviour](https://www.kapwing.com/w/4mXSYdjoNA)

[APP ref link](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=webtoons&c=apps&hl=en-IN)

I want to achieve this behaviour in API  Level 23..to..31

What is the correct way to achieve this behaviour without using deprecated code ?

Thanks

I have tried multiple solutions as mentioned below but none of the gives the required behaviour and also few methods below are deprecated.

```
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

-> requireActivity().window.setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

-> windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

-> requireActivity().window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)

-> requireActivity().window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

**UPDATE**

I am able achieve the required behaviour only on Devices without notch using this code
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JBJh.png)

but fails for the devices with notch ,content wont get covered under status bar in full screen mode gives a black space in the status bar region

tried
[tried method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUY8b.png)
but didn’t help

And also content resizes as I exit full screen mode content goes under visible status bar

**Above code is deprecate in API level 30 appreciate if could share exact non-deprecated alternative code**

**UPDATE2**

was able to find the solution for all android version[as mentioned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnW5a.png)

for more details refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492550/22058944)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: show/hide status bar/power bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273186/android-show-hide-status-bar-power-bar)

Comment: @StanislavBondar this doesn’t help as per my requirement and also FLAG_FULLSCREEN flag is deprecated on Android version R(API lvl 30) onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set following flags for window

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
```

**SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE** : This flag indicates that the application's stable content should appear behind the system bars (status bar and navigation bar). It allows your application to use the space normally occupied by the system bars so that your content doesn't resize when the system bars hide or show.

**SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN** : This flag indicates that the application wants to occupy the entire screen, including the space behind the system bars. When this flag is set, the content of your application can extend into the area normally reserved for the status bar at the top of the screen.

I hope it will work for your scenario

Comment: sorry @hammad this doesn’t address the requirement and moreover the flags and "systemUiVisibility" is deprecated

Comment: I have tested it in android 12 and it is working fine.

Comment: deprecated now. need to use solution based on InsetsController

Answer (score -1):

was able to find the solution for all android version [as mentioned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqnVu.png)
for more details refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492550/22058944)